# std::async with temporary future returned

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, stl, future

Here is exerpt from [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/)

> If the std::future obtained from std::async has temporary object
>   lifetime (not moved or bound to a variable), the destructor of the
>   std::future will block at the end of the full expression until the
>   asynchronous operation completes, essentially code such as the
>   following synchronous:

```
std::async(std::launch::async, []{ f(); }); // temporary's dtor waits for f()
std::async(std::launch::async, []{ g(); }); // does not start until f() completes
```

But when i tried with VC++:

```
void fasync(char ch)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
        cout << ch << endl;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    async(launch::async, [] { fasync('+'); });
    async(launch::async, [] { fasync('*'); });

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2000));

    return 0;
}
```

i got something like this

> +
>   *
>   +*
>
> *+
>
> *+
>
> *
>   +
>   *+
>
> +*
>
> +*
>
> +*
>
> +*

Looks like nobody waits for fasync('+')?

First i thought that it is because of sleep and changed fasync to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    cout << ch << endl;
}
cin.get();
```

but output interleaving again.

**EDIT: According to the link provided by T.C. it is a known bug of VS 2013.**

Comment: Which version of MSVC? 2013 and earlier are nonconforming in this respect.

Comment: There we go. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/810623/std-futures-destructor-not-blocking-async-thread-when-using-launch-policy-launch-async